# I am vb.net programmer I want print RDLC report directly without report viewer

Tags: vb.net-2010

Hi all I want print Rdlc report without report viewer in vb.net 2010 I develop pos billing software i print invoice directly to printer but rdlc report not print.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: i was tray but not working